# When doing inheritance, why not simply modify the [[Prototype]] property of the derived class

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have been reading a lot lately about some core concepts of JS and inheritance is a bit confusing.

Here are the methods that I know of:

```
// Base class
function Parent(foo) {
  if (foo === undefined) {
    throw new TypeError('foo is undefined');
  }

  this.foo = foo;
}

// Derived class
function Child(foo, bar) {
  if (foo === undefined) {
    throw new TypeError('foo is undefined');
  }

  if (bar === undefined) {
    throw new TypeError('bar is undefined');
  }

  Parent.call(this, foo);
  this.bar = bar;
}
```

### 1. Using a temporary function

```
function tmpFn(){}
tmpFn.prototype = Parent.prototype;
Child.prototype = new tmpFn();
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

### 2. Using a `Parent` instance

```
Child.prototype = new Parent();       // fail
Child.prototype = new Parent(null);   // hax
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

### 3. Using `Object#create`

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
```

---

After examining the prototype chains for all methods, I realised that they all yield the same result (which is kind of obvious).
But in all these methods, there's one thing that's common.
We are creating a third object to replace the prototype and then re-set the constructor.
are two overrides involved:-

1. `Child.prototype = ...`
2. `Child.prototype.constructor = Child`

This got me thinking: Why not simply do `Child.prototype.__proto__ = Parent.prototype`?
Or a *safer* alternative, `Object.setPrototypeOf(Child.prototype, Parent.prototype)`.

What's the harm in this?

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla sums up why modifying `__proto__` is a bad idea:

> Warning: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine. The effects on performance of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to simply the time spent in `obj.__proto__` = ... statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose [[Prototype]] has been altered. If you care about performance you should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using Object.create().

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

The `Object.setPrototypeOf` method comes with a similar warning about performance:

> Warning: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine. The effects on performance of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to simply the time spent in obj.**proto** = ... statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose [[Prototype]] has been altered. If you care about performance you should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object. Instead, create a new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using Object.create().

Performance issues aside, they continue with warning that `__proto__` is a legacy feature:

> Warning: While Object.prototype.**proto** is supported today in most browsers, its existence and exact behavior has only been standardized in the ECMAScript 2015 specification as a legacy feature to ensure compatibility for web browsers.

Source: Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Furthermore, many browsers allowed you to set the `__proto__` property, which allows man in the middle attacks within your class hierarchy (not that this is the only way to do that in JavaScript).

The reason to use `Object.create` is simple:

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

The `Object.create` method was explicitly created to provide a mechanism for setting up prototypal inheritance, and optionally including definitions for additional properties to avoid the two other workarounds/hacks that you proposed:

- Using a temporary constructor function pointing to the parent class's prototype
- Creating a throwaway instance of the parent class, which is not properly initialized, as a means for setting up the prototype chain.